# Increment of $\arg(f(z))$ after one rotation

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading a paper and the author defines $\Delta=\arg(f(z))$ to be the increment of $\arg(f(z))$ when $\arg(z)$ for $z=e^{i\phi}$ changes from $0$ to $2\pi$. I understand that we're looking to find the difference of the arguments of $f(z)$ after $z$ makes one full rotation around the unit circle, but I'm also confused: $e^{i0}=e^{i2\pi}$ so $f(e^{i0})=f(e^{i2\pi})$, so would $\Delta$ be anything besides 0?!

Thanks for the help, I'm new to complex analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but the increment is the difference between the arguments of $f(z)$, not between the values of $f$. You have a function $f:G \to \mathbb{C}$ when $G \subset \mathbb{C}$ an open domain which contains the unit circle. Now let's define a curve $\gamma:[0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{C}$ by the rule $\gamma(t)=f(e^{it})$. Then by your definition the increment is $arg(\gamma(2\pi))-arg(\gamma(0))$. Yes, the values of $\gamma(2\pi)$ and $\gamma(0)$ are the same, but their arguments can still be different. For example, if $f$ is the identity function ($f(z)=z$) then you will get $\gamma(0)=e^{i0}$ but $\gamma(2\pi)=e^{2i\pi}$. The *location* of these points on the complex plane is the same but their arguments are different-$0$ and $2\pi$ respectively. So the increment here will be $2\pi$. Intuitively the increment is $2\pi$ multiplied by the number of rotations that the curve $\gamma$ does around the origin. A rotation counterclockwise counts as 1 rotation, a rotation clockwise counts as -1 rotation.

Comment: "The location of these points on the complex plane is the same but their arguments are different." The location of a point determines exactly its modulus and argument, right? for instance, the point $z=3$ has a modulus of $3$ and an argument of $0$.

Comment: Not really. Imagine you make a counterclockwise rotation around the origin and return to the same point. You added $2\pi$ to the argument, right? So $2\pi$ is also an argument of $z=3$. Same thing about $4\pi,-2\pi,100\pi$ and so on. Every complex number has infinitely many arguments, and the difference between each two is $2\pi$ times an integer. So the modulus of a number is a  function, but the argument is not, because it is multi-valued.

Comment: Aha, I guess this is some sort of convention. I'll take that.